# How/Why Drupal node permissions get corrupted?

Tags: drupal, permissions

Our application is using Drupal 6. Occasionally our Drupal node permissions get corrupted, and rebuilding node permissions generally takes care of it. I observed this happening in a working environment just like that.

I am just trying to understand how/why these permissions can get corrupted? Or is there something we can do to avoid this issue.

One reason I found online is Drupal upgrade. But, in our case, the only change to the system is new nodes got added over the time by users and RSS feeds.

Greatly appreciate if somebody can help me with more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be, what one of Your modules has some hooks, which modifies the permissions system of Drupal. One of such hooks could be [hook_perm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6). You could check Your modules for it's presence.